# Comparing the growth rates of 2 functions

Tags: limits, functions

Say you're given two functions $f(x)=\ln(x)$ and $g(x)=\log_2(x)$.

How would I go about comparing the growth rates of these functions? I'm aware that it involves taking limits, but how do I use that to get the proper notation?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Recall that

$$\log_2 x =\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}$$